# Product Variation attribute won't pass WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create a Variation for a variable type product using WooCommerce Rest API (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#create-a-product-variation). Sadly, whenever I create one, it creates the product variation with the correct price and image, but the attribute which is being passed doesn't get selected. even though it exists in the product attributes tab and selected as a "Variations attribute"

I tried passing the attribute options as an array, a string, and what not. the id of the attribute was always correct as well as the id of the product. keys are definitely right since the variation is created but it doesn't contain the attribute.

Here's an example in cURL, even there I couldn't get it done. so it isn't related to my C# code for sure:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/IDHERE/variations \
    -u cc:cc \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{  
   "regular_price":"549.99",
   "image":{  
      "src":"https://www.cookingclassy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/hummus-31.jpg"
   },
   "attributes":[  
      {  
         "id":9,
         "options": "olive"
      }
   ]
}'
```

The product variation should be listed with it's attribute/s. as well as the image and price that are currently listed correctly.

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug that avoids adding Variation Attribute 'option' values to Attributes with Hebrew names.
Please read bug report no. 24312: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/24312